# Can I miss puppies?

Tags: kingdom-hearts

I'm going for the secret movie, and part of that is getting all of the puppies. I also have to go through and seal all the worlds. Is it possible, via general plot, or by sealing a specific world, to miss a set of puppies?

**Basically, are any puppies missable?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, none of the puppies are missable, but there are some that can *seem* missable. By that I mean, the areas in which they are become harder to access later in the game. These puppies are:

- **55-57, and 73-81 (3 sets)** - They are in Monstro. You can get back to Monstro, but you may have to fly through that area a few times before he is there.
- **43-45** - In the clocktower at Neverland. If you wait too far in the game, you'll have to fight the optional boss to be able to access the area again
- **49-54** - At the Cave of Wonders in Agrabah. Same as above, an optional boss will need to be defeated if you wait until later in the game.